# Rails session data - Store in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, hash

I have a form on a rails view that submits data to a page that will represent a shopping cart summary page.

When I submit the data to the next page they are transmitted as follows according the console output.

```
"team"=>{"team_name"=>"Joe Blogs", "email"=>"joe@bloggs.com", "player1"=>"
3", "player2"=>"4", "player3"=>"5"}
```

I want to store this data is a session variable namely as a hash so if another team gets submitted to the summary page I can add it to the session as another hash entry. i.e. team[1], team[2].
Then I can access team[1].team_name, etc. and use it accordingly.

In summary, I want a user to be able to fill out a form and have it put into their cart. They can then go back and do the same again. Finally the can look at their cart and remove any records they don't want, clear the cart or submit what they choose into the database.

I can't find out how to do it or if it's even possible.

Any solutions or suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily store a hash in Rails session.

Example:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    session[:cart] = {"team_name"=>"Joe Blogs", "email"=>"joe@bloggs.com", "player1"=>"3", "player2"=>"4", "player3"=>"5"}
  end
end
```

But, by default, Rails stores sessions in cookies, and a cookie size is limited to just 4 kilobytes of data, so if your hash is going to contain more than a few keys, you will need to use something else for session storage, e.g. the database.

To store session in the database you can use the [activerecord-session_store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store) gem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I wanted to access just the team_name part of the session[:cart] can I still get to it? Also if I wanted multiple entries could can a session give me session [:cart][1] for example. Sorry if they seem basic but trying to work out how to implement this.

Comment: Yes, `session[:cart]` can hold arrays and hashes, so it will return you whatever you put there. E.g. `session[:cart]['team_name']`

Comment: Great so can session[:cart][1] can also hold a hash and I can access that by session[:cart][1]['team_name'] if I sat session[:cart][1] = {"team_name"=>"Joe Blogs", "email"=>"joe@bloggs.com", "player1"=>"3", "player2"=>"4", "player3"=>"5"}? That would then allow me to store a few "teams" in the session?

Comment: set it to `session[:cart] = [{"team_name"=>"Team 1"}, {"team_name"=>"Team 2"}]`, then `session[:cart][0]` will return `{"team_name"=>"Team 1"}`

Comment: I have been able to assign the initial hash to the session but having trouble assigning a subsequent one. Each hash that is passed to the session can have 5 different values so how can I saw that if session[:cart][x] exists then put it in the next empty session where x is the last session store. Not sure if this is even possible? I then want to be able to remove session[:cart][x] if a user decides to remove that hash?

Comment: Use `session[:cart].length` to know how many items are there, and use `session[:cart].delete_at(some_index)` to remove something, and, I believe, after removing you need to reassign the session again, `session[:cart] = session[:cart]`.

Comment: Getting somewhere now but I have the following code:
`team_values = params[:team]
   if session[:teams] then
    for i in 0..3
      puts session[:teams]['0']
      puts session[:teams]['#{i}']
    end
   else
     session[:teams] = {}
     @TeamsHash = session[:teams]
     @TeamsHash[0] = team_values
     session[:teams] = @TeamsHash
     puts session[:teams][0]
   end
`
I am able to get an item into the hash using [0] if it doesn't exist. I have 2 problems in the if loop. Why does it only print when I use ['0'] where I can assign using [0].  And if I want to put i in the loop it doesn't work

Comment: try to replace `'#{i}'` with `"#{i}"`, single-quotes are not interpolated in ruby, only the double quotes are.

Comment: No still getting no output from the first statement.
`puts session[:teams]["#{i}"]
      puts session[:teams]['0']`
As where I'm getting as expected from the second statement.

Comment: dump the entire session using `p session[:teams]` and look what's inside

Comment: `{"0"=>{"team_name"=>"Alan", "email"=>"joe@bloggs.com", "player1"=>"406", "player2"=>"389", "player3"=>"416"}}`

Comment: Any idea on how I can use the interpolation? Was to be able to use `i` rather than hard code it.